# How to remove a class from an object after a certien window width has passed

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a bunch of LI elements and each of them have classes. So due to responsiveness, i want to remove those classes after 1050px. I havent tried writing it in jQuery yet, but if you think it makes it work by any chance then feel free to use jQuery. 
PS: no i can not just overwrite the properties in CSS, i HAVE to remove them.

```js
var itemsArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".list li"));
var i = 0;
function check(){
if(this.innerWidth <= 1050){
    for(i = 0; i<itemsArray.length;i++){
        itemsArray[i].classList.remove('disblck');
        itemsArray[i].classList.remove('disnone');
    }
}
}
window.onload = check();
window.onresize = check();
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
            <li class='disblck first2'>
                <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
                <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

                <h3>John Purcell</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disblck first2'>
                <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
                <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disblck second2'>
                <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
                <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disblck second2'>
                <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
                <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disnone third2'>
                <img src="../images2/PHP.png" />
                <h2>PhP and MySQL For Beginners</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disnone  third2'>
                <img src="../images2/c++.png" />
                <h2>C++ for absolute begginers</h2>

                <h3>John Purcell</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disnone fourth2'>
                <img src="../images2/JS.jpg" />
                <h2>JavaScript From Scratch</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
            <li class='disnone fourth2'>
                <img src="../images2/cSharp.png" />
                <h2>C# From Begginer To Advanced</h2>

                <h3>Derek Banas</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: _"no i can not just overwrite the properties in CSS, i HAVE to remove them"_ <- why? Sounds like you're making assumptions that are limiting you're potential solution. How about you explain clearly what it is you want to achieve through this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not apply the styles associated with that class within a media query so they only come into effect under 1050px?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .disblck {
    /* styles */
  }

  .disnone {
    /* styles */
  }
}
```

Comment: Because they conflict with other properties... I abused the !important rule and dont have much time to rework the code... I wrote this 2 years ago and im revisiting it because its for a competition in my school...

Comment: @KeyBasher your questions mentions nothing of this. What are the conflicts? Surely you could create CSS rules that are more specific

Comment: Do as @Phil suggests and make your CSS selector more specific. e.g. `li.disblck` will override `li` or `disblck` as long as you include `!important` where needed. Add another class to all `<li>` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Despite best practice, it looks like you still want to remove those CSS classes when the window is above 1050px (I mean, to the haters, his handle is "KeyBasher" lolz).

You can add a resize event handler to the window object

```
function handleAbove1050px(){
  const isAbove1050px = window.innerWidth > 1050

  if(isAbove1050px) {
    // remove the classes
    itemsArray.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('disblck')
      item.classList.remove('disnone')
    })
  }
  else {
    // add them back
    itemsArray.forEach(item => {
      item.classList.add('disblck')
      item.classList.add('disnone')
    })
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleAbove1050px)
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8p3wrcg/1/

Comment: @KeyBasher - this work for you? did you check out the jsfiddle link?